# DownloadManager throws security exception when download folder is in sd card

Tags: java, android, kotlin, security, permissions

on android pi one user,who have downloads folder on sd card,get exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Памятный-камень-Кул-Шариф.jpg: Neither user 10244 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1594)
at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1479)
```

I download files using this code:

```
    fun loadUrl(uri: Uri, index: Int) {
    val request: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,uri.lastPathSegment)
    loadIds[index] = dM.enqueue(request)
    }
```

Yes,i can use try/catch for this code,but may be exists another way,to check,should i request write/read external storage for download folder? Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Add this in your android manifest.xml file

Comment: Which code is producing that exception?

Comment: Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before use. But.. you did not tell how you got that path.

Comment: @blackapps I download photos,and i decided download it in download folder.

Comment: Your remark makes no sense.

Comment: @blackapps What path you mean? If path to photo,i get it from webview,and i get last segment from uri,to get name of file.

Comment: I have no idea what you do. Or how one could get a path from webview. Or which code would produce that exception. Please post reproducable code.

Comment: @blackapps exception is in line:             loadIds[index] = dM.enqueue(request),i.e when we start loading file on sd card in downloads folder.

Comment: I again have this exception (my friend have this in api 33).